# Definition of success function

Tags: python, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, sicp

In church numerals, if we have:

```
# (define zero (lambda (f) (lambda (x) x)))
zero = lambda f: lambda x: x
```

Then the successor function can be defined as:

```
# (define succ (lambda (n) (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f ((n f) x))))))
succ = lambda n: lambda f: lambda x: f(n(f)(x))
```

Maybe this is a silly question, but if the successor essentially adds one more wrapper `f(...)` to the previous equation, why couldn't this just be defined as `f(n)`? Is this more for consistency of definition, or why can't that shorter form be used?

(Note: using python definitions here as well as scheme as it makes it a bit simpler for me to test with.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numeral `n` is defined as `n` applications of the function `f` to some argument `x`.

Thus,

```
0 = λf.λx.x
1 = λf.λx.f x
2 = λf.λx.f (f x)
3 = λf.λx.f (f (f (x))
...
```

Note that 1 is not the same as `λf.λx.f 0`, so `succ 0` can't be, either. (The same is true for the other numerals.)

Your definition, `λn.λf.λx.(f n)` would give

```
succ 0 = (λn.λf.λx.(f n)) (λg.λy.y)
       = λf.λx.f (λg.λy.y)
```

which is not the same as 1, but

```
 (λn.λf.λx.f (n f x)) (λg.λy.y)
= λf.λx.f ((λg.λy.y) f x)
= λf.λx.f ((λy.y) x)
= λf.λx.f x
= 1
```